# Crontan scheduler with sidekiq - trying to set it for every day at 2pm Eastern Time

Tags: sidekiq

I'm using the `sidekiq-scheduler` gem and everything works perfectly fine whenever I'm scheduling a worker to run every X minutes or hours. However, if I'm trying to run a sidekiq worker at 2pm eastern time every day, I cannot seem to get this to work. Here's what my `sidekiq.yml` file looks like:

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 200
  :schedule:
    purge_worker:
      cron: '16 14 * * * * America/Detroit'   # Every day at 2pm eastern
      class: PureWorker
      queue: development
```

To my knowledge, the above configuration is what I would set for the worker to kick off every day at 2:16pm. I keep incrementing its minute just to test it out, but I cannot get the sidekiq worker to go off. The other ones that are scheduled to run once a minute are working just fine, but just not this one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One too many asterisks. This worked:

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 200
  :schedule:
    purge_worker:
      cron: '16 14 * * * America/Detroit'   # Every day at 2pm eastern
      class: PureWorker
      queue: development
```